# IE 10 works locally with @font-face, but not when viewing page from server

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face, internet-explorer-10, webfonts

I'm using a custom created  web font from icomoon that's hosted on my own server. Was amazed at how easy everything was. Tested locally on all browsers. Works great (even down to IE7 and firefox 4)! Tested again from my server and it doesn't work in IE10.

Pretty sure I'm declaring the fonts right:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Here's a link to the test site http://www.corysgrilledcheese.com/store/ if you want to take a look.

And here's a link to screenshots http://www.corysgrilledcheese.com/store/fontsBroken.png of what it looks like when I load the page locally, and then with the same browser viewing the page from a server.

I've been scouring the web, but no luck so far. Any suggestions on a solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: It works in IE10 for me.

Comment: Interesting - excluding my instance of Windows, it's worked 50% of the time. Are you aware of any changes to your browser preferences? Maybe a security setting? My version of IE 10 is a default install.

Comment: No, I can't think of any changes I've made to my IE10 from default. Try to use IE's Developer Tools and/or Fiddler2/Wireshark to debug. One thing I just noticed is that `icomoon.eot` has a weird MIME type (compare to the one returned by Google fonts), it might be something to do with that.

Comment: Looks like your code is working. Please check security settings of "Internet zone" of IE. There just a bit below halfway down of the window you can find something like "Import settings", radio buttons on the first field control, if external fonts can be imported.

Answer (score 6):

Teemu found the root cause: on many corporate managed machines, downloading fonts is completely disabled. It's in Internet Explorer's Settings:  Security Settings-Internet Zone > Downloads > Font Download. Options are Enabled, Disabled and Prompt. If disabled you get nothing.

This basically means that I don't feel comfortable using icon fonts for IE 10, and probably 9. Though 7 and 8 had no issues.

Comment: We had the same issue in IE11. Their corporate machines had "Fonts" disabled. Screenshot: http://img.ly/xtl9